# Why does putting a 1/2 in front of the squared error make the math easier?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-function

Per wiki, the mean squared error (MSE) [looks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Predictor) like:

$$
\operatorname {MSE} ={\frac {1}{m}}\sum _{i=1}^{m}(y_{i}-{\hat y_{i}})^{2}
$$

The [professor](https://youtu.be/K69jbdvMPMc?t=302) added a $1\over2$ in front of the formula and explained it a little bit. I am a little bit confused. How does putting a $1\over2$ in front of the squared error make the math easier?

Comment: Just a guess, but it may simplify mathematics involving the derivative.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A major reason for using MSE is to optimize the parameters of a regression model. From calculus, you know how to find the minimum of a function by taking the derivative. That puts a "2" out in front, which is irritating to keep writing, so it is reasonable to put a "1/2" at the beginning so the derivative doesn't need a constant out front.

We get away with it because the minima of $f(x)$ and $\frac{f(x)}{2}$ are achieved at the same value(s) of $x$.